# Обработка url

Tags: node.js, express, django

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста. Django обрабатывает красиво url
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/

```
 urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^articles/2003/$', 'news.views.special_case_2003'),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/$', 'news.views.year_archive'),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/$', 'news.views.month_archive'),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]+)/$', 'news.views.article_detail'),
]
```

Есть ли такая возможность в Node.js в Express или другом фреймворке? И как это можно сделать (статья, пример)? Спасибо за помощь и ваше время.

Comment: Почти любой современный фреймворк умеет роутинг.

Comment: В итоге я хочу получить, чтоб в url браузера было:
www.domain.com/news.views/special_case_2003 - к примеру

Comment: зачем там слово views ?

Comment: Мне нужно и меть возможность самому задавать url для страниц сайта.

Comment: @RubaXa вам написал как, что не устраивает ?

    app.get("/news.views/:article_name",news.views);

Comment: а на что будет вести ссылка news.views? Можно пример?

Comment: news.views - метод объекта news, какой пример вам нужен ?

Comment: а что содержит объект news? строку? то есть вместо news.views я могу просто поставить любую строку?

Comment: не знаю что содержит объект news, например он может быть набром "контроллеров" для обработки callback роутеров, вы почитайте доки и по js и по express,  не пытайтесь писать на js как на python - ничего не выйдет.

Answer (score 5):

Нее, красиво, это так:

```
app.get("/articles/2003", function (req, res) { });
app.get("/articles/:year", function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.params); // { year: "2014" }
});
app.get("/articles/:year/:month", function (req, res) {
     console.log(req.params); // { year: "2014", month: "7" }
});  
app.get("/articles/:year/:month/:id", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.params); // { year: "2014", month: "7", id: "123" }
});
```

Comment: ну да, писать контроллеры в описательной части (роутинге) - что может быть красивее и изолированней.

Comment: @Etki я думаю это пример, вы же понимаете что может быть написано и как в моем  комменте, а для демонстрации это хороший способ (чтобы было видно параметры callback); ну и вообще express это не mvc, поэтому говорить о моделях, контроллерах и прочем неуместно.

Comment: @eicto

> ну и вообще express это не mvc, поэтому говорить о моделях, контроллерах и прочем неуместно.

Да хоть трактором назвать, смысл не меняется. Понятия не имею, что подгружается у express при каждом запросе, но опять же, ссылаться в описательной части на конкретные функции - вряд ли красиво.

Comment: @eicto нет, я им не пользовался. Но это никак невлияет на вышесказанное. Я не говорю, что это не работает, но это не очень подходит под слово красиво.

Comment: вот как сделано в sails, http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/routes когда routes - custom не сильно отличается от app.get('/controller/:action',controller.action);

Comment: @Etki ок, покажите как красиво.

---

это не "сперва добейся" это вопрос - может вы видели какие-то более красивые решения подобных случаев, всё что я видел в своей жизни - когда требования нестандартные, роутеры всегда выглядят похоже на пример выше. Если же вы не знаете более красивых решений, то критика просто неконструктивна.

Comment: строка не шибко отличается от ссылки, какая разница писать обработчик грубо говоря 

   if (isFunction(callback)) {}

или

   if (controllerHasFunction('method')) {} 

?

Comment: @eicto

> С таким конфигом можно хотя бы независимо потестить, не привязываясь к каким-то реальным функциям.

Обработчик может и без разницы как писать. Но софтвейр никогда нельзя писать, отталкиваясь от удобства в каких-то узких конкретных случаях, есть тот же single responsibility principle, иначе получается вордпресс.